# Empty message while receiving data from socket

Tags: c#, sockets, ussd

I'm trying to connect to an UAP Server (used for sending and receiving USSD messages in Huawei) using `Socket` class but there's a problem while receiving data from server. I can connect to server correctly and also I can send data to server but I have problem with receiving data.

This is my code for connecting and sending message:

```
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); //server
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 2020);

clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

clientSocket.Connect(remoteEP);

//bind to socket, here I send bind message
Bind();
```

and inside the `Bind` function, I call `receive` method to get data from server:

```
private static void receive()
{
    try
    {
        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = clientSocket;

        // Begin receiving the data from the remote device.
        clientSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(receiveCallback), state);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("receive | " + ex.ToString());
    }

}//receive
```

Here you can see my Wireshark log while connecting, sending data and receiving data from server:

[image: Wireshark log]

But as you can see, last two messages from server are highlighted with red color which means there's a problem with receiving data from server. Also I don't see `data` field in details:

[image: detail of a message]

I really don't know what's the problem, is this a problem with server or not? Should I use another Socket client to connect and receive data from server or not?

Comment: I used UAP protocol for sending receiving ussd message in english, have you tried arabic messages ? arabic messages appear as several Question marks like this ??? on phone, any clue ??

Comment: @MSUH Yes, I'm sending Arabic/Persian texts over UAP, all you need is to set `CodeScheme` to 0x48 and encode the strings in UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks, it was solved, there was some issue on service provider side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TCP reset packets aren't a part of your application level protocol and your application shouldn't be expected to see them.

Exactly what is the incorrect behavior with your application, because with what you've posted, I'm not seeing any problems.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by `TCP reset packets`?

Comment: your red highlighted entries from wireshark.  They are RST ACK packets (look at your screenshots).  You aren't supposed to see those in your application.  There is also no data associated with them.